# Share customer account in multi shop with session id in Magento

Tags: magento, session, magento-1.7

We have a multishop setup and are trying to share the shopping cart in Magento. We are using the tutorial at http://turnkeye.com/blog/share-magento-cart-between-multistores/ and are by part 2. In this part there is explained how to share customer account by session id as following:

3. If you have different domains, in this case you can add session ID to the URL for another store. Use this construction "Mage::getModel('core/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('...')" to get the URL with session parameter.

We are trying to make this work, but do not find out where we have to place / replace the "Mage::getModel('core/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('...')".

Can someone help us how to insert this part?

Comment: have you enabled persistent cart in admin?

Comment: Not yet, I just looked up how to set it up and that is easy. What would the use be in this case to set it up. And if I am correct it would not solve the question?

Comment: if you enable persistent cart you should be able to change from one store to another with your session data intact - including the basket (provided the next store has those products available)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we tested this yesterday, but we do not keep the shopping cart over different urls so shop1.com / shop2.com / shop3.com. Can it be that this only works by storeviews and not seperate urls?

Comment: He Coen, ware you able to resolve this? I'm stuck at the same problem trying to share the cart over a multi-store multi-domain install

Comment: Hi Jason, No did not do it in the end. Now going over to Magento 2 and will see if we can manage something simmular there. Succes!